# MapView not showing location and Pins?

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview

Im working on a mapview but Its not showing the user location like I want and also the Pins, I dont know if the code is correct, I think it is, so I need your help.

Heres the code for showing the location with a zoom:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.MapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    coordinateuser.latitude = self.MapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    coordinateuser.longitude = self.MapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinateuser, 1200, 1200);
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.MapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    });
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And heres the code for displaying a MKPinAnnotationView, this is the one that I think is wrong:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
static NSString *SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =
    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];

        return annotationView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    cmtlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.502519,-99.259779);
    //UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
    //annotationView.image = flagImage;
    [annotation setCoordinate:cmtlocation];
    return pinView;

}
```

So I will appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's the other way around than what the other answer says:

If the dequeue returns nil, code is creating an *empty* `MKAnnotationView`.
`MKAnnotationView` is empty by default so the annotations (*including* the user location) are invisible.  At the top of `viewForAnnotation`, check if `annotation` is of type `MKUserLocation` and return `nil`.  For other annotations, create an `MKAnnotationView` if you want to use a custom `image`.  Otherwise, create (alloc+init) an `MKPinAnnotationView` which automatically provides a pin image.

Additionally...

You are not even calling `addAnnotation` for your custom annotation.  You should not be setting the annotation's `coordinate` in the `viewForAnnotation` method.  Instead, you should be creating an annotation object (eg. in `viewDidLoad`), setting its `coordinate` and `title` and then calling `addAnnotation`.

Also, in `viewDidLoad`, you are trying to access the user location coordinates *immediately* after setting `showsUserLocation` to `YES`.  The user location will not be available immediately.  Instead, move the `setRegion` call to the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method (or just set `userTrackingMode` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong, as you expected: If

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
```

does not return `nil`, you return just another annotation view:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
return annotationView;
```

Otherwise, you try to set a property of a `nil` object:

```
pinView.annotation = annotation;
```

and then do something else before returning `nil`:

```
cmtlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.502519,-99.259779);
//UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
//annotationView.image = flagImage;
[annotation setCoordinate:cmtlocation];
return pinView;
```